# I am trying to run a Collatz conjecture sequence to see if it always ends at 1, but my number is stuck at 999. Why is this?

Tags: python, python-2.7, segmentation-fault, sequence, collatz

Here is my code:

```
def isEven(number):
    return number % 2 == 0

def run(x):
    z = x
    while z != 1:
        if isEven(z) == True:
            z = z/2
            print z
        else:
            z = (3*z)+1
            print z
    else:
        print 'Got one!'
        #To see if the collatz does indeed always work
    x+=1
```

It works up until 999, at which it continues indefinitely, print `Got one! 999`, eventually raising a `Segmentation Fault: 22`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Where does `x` come from? Full stack trace? Also as you never `break` your loop, you will always enter the `else`.

Comment: "Got one!" - got a what? What are you trying to get? What does that message mean?

Comment: How can you say that this snippet "works up until 999", if you assign the local variable x to z, before defining x itself...

Comment: And where does the `999` come from, anyway? Your `print` statement doesn't print any numbers. Can you make sure the code you post actually demonstrates the behavior your question is asking about?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use a `sys.setrecursionlimit` to stop the 999 from repeating forever. Here is an edited version of your code. I put a `sys.argv[]` as well, just for fun because I imported `sys`. The `sys.argv[]` gets the argument after you run your program like this: `python myscript.py 13.5` In this, `sys.argv[1]` is `13.5`. I set the recursion limit pretty high, but the downfall of this is that the `Segmentation Fault: 22` still occurs, and I haven't found a way to get rid of that.

```
import time
import sys
while True:
    try:
        var = int(sys.argv[1])
        break
    except IndexError:
        print 'You have to enter a number!'
        var = int(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
        break

def check(x):
    z = x
    try:
        while z != 1:
            if isEven(z) == True:
                z = z/2
                print z
            else:
                z = (3*z)+1
                print z


        else:
            print 'Got one!'
            x = x+1
            print 'Trying for %d...' %(x)
            check(x)
    except:
        print 'You were at number %d' %(x)
        check(x)

def isEven(number):
        return number % 2 == 0

sys.setrecursionlimit(10000000)
check(var)
```

Comment: The OP's posted code isn't even recursive. Do you have access to a more representative version of the OP's code?

Comment: Also, `sys.setrecursionlimit` is not a solution to stack overflows. Unless you know exactly what you're doing, it just turns a Python stack overflow into a C stack overflow. The correct fix for recursion limit problems is generally to use an iterative solution.

Comment: Well, it worked for me! :)

Comment: This is funny. Even if the Collatz conjecture were false, THIS program would never find the proof...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cleaner version:

```
def collatz(x):
    yield x
    while x > 1:
        if x & 1:
            # x is odd
            x = 3*x + 1
            yield x
        # x is now even
        x //= 2
        yield x

def main():
    for x in xrange(2, 5000):
        print('-'*20)
        print(','.join(str(c) for c in collatz(x)))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```